# Replacing ceiling pull chain light fixture with multiple wires

Tags: wiring, lighting, light-fixture

Apologies if this is a simple question, but I was hoping to replace an old ceiling light fixture with a pull chain that has broken. The examples of similar fixtures I have seen are all wired in using two wires, which are simply connected to the correct sides of the fixture. However, my fixture seems to have four wires, two of which are black and two of which are white, with the black wires both being attached to one contact and both of the white wires attached to the opposite contact.(Apologies for the poor image). [image]

On the right you can see the two different white wires going into the same contact. My question is on how to rewire using a new plastic fixture with two contacts - should both black wires be attached on the same contact as here, or should only one be (similarly with the white wires)? Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: You have a cable coming in with power and a cable going out with power(from the in cable).  The light is just in the centre of them.  Usually in this case you use a short wire(of the same colour) to connect to the light, if the light only has one screw per side(one wire per screw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Wire it exactly the same (if the new fixture properly accepts two wires per contact.)
2. Wire "pigtails" (short wires of the same color) to the current wires joined to the current fixture, and wire the other end of the pigtails to the new fixture, otherwise exactly the same. That permits you to maintain the connectedness of the two current wires while having only a single wire to each fixture connection point.